# Is it possible to create a responsive image carousel that stays in flow

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, carousel

Everytime I try and build a responsive image carousel I have to take the image out of the flow of the HTML at some point using absolute positioning.

Is it not possible to create a carousel where the current image is 100% width of it's container, the other images are hidden in the overflow, and the whole thing is not taken out of flow such that whatever text comes after it in the resulting DOM doesn't ignore the carousel all-together and end up in a funky position in the top left corner behind the images?

Consider this HTML:

```
<div id="featured">
<div id="featured-title">
    Title
</div>
<div id="featured-images">
    <div class="featured-images-image">
        <img src="lib/imgs/fi-1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-images-image">
        <img src="lib/imgs/fi-1.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="featured-content">
    <div id="featured-content-text">
        <h3>
            Title
        </h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vel enim id massa suscipit vehicula non sit amet augue. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed nisi urna, volutpat nec justo vel, rhoncus fermentum dolor. Integer pharetra, lectus eget auctor consectetur, tellus mauris gravida eros, nec porta augue tortor ac nibh. Fusce aliquam vel risus vitae luctus. Etiam lacinia ultricies tellus, nec venenatis magna viverra eu. Etiam tincidunt nibh hendrerit tincidunt ullamcorper. Nunc non urna congue, ultrices lacus sollicitudin, pellentesque ante. Etiam mi leo, sollicitudin ac tempus a, semper eu justo. Donec eget elementum dolor. Proin non tellus facilisis, suscipit velit eu, imperdiet urna. Proin non nulla suscipit, cursus tellus eleifend, tristique justo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis luctus velit et pellentesque faucibus.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

How would I go about making the width of the first image 100%, hiding the second (and any other) image ready to animate-in, while also staying within the flow of the document such that the text below it stays below the carousel area.

Is this even possible? I'm yet to understand how HTML professionals haven't completely lost the plot with this markup language. I understand that if I was to explicitly force the width and height of the containing elements then I wouldn't need to worry about the image being taken out of the flow - but responsiveness is key here.

Answer (score 0):

The responsive carousel I've used in the past is [Flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/), which resizes based on the image so would scale down on smaller devices. It might be worth checking out.